# Pi 4 doesn't want to use ethernet port

Tags: pi-4, ethernet

Edit: I might be able to communicate with the port to some extent, see bottom

My pi doesn't seem to even acknowledge the ethernet port's existence. There are no lights at the port, and there doesn't seem to be anything in software. `dmesg` show nothing related to it, nor does `journalctl`. I can run `sudo ip link set eth0 up` as much as I want, and it still shows as down. Nothing shows up in journalctl or dmesg when I unplug or replug it, and everything behaves identically whether it's plugged in or not. It is probably not an issue with the cable, as using my laptop it gets 233 Mbsp down and 11.5 Mbsp up.
This started happening after it got bumped a while ago so the port is probably just dead, but I was wondering if anyone had any idea what else it might be.

Output of `ip link` after running `sudo ip link set eth0 up`. Note that this does not change if I unplug the cable:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:15:f2:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:15:f2:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Edit: Actually, I may have found a sign of life. Following is the output of `ethtool eth0`. It used to give an output with very little information, but then when I tried it again a few minutes later it gave this instead.

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 10Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: gs
    Wake-on: d
        SecureOn password: 00:00:00:00:00:00
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

When I run `dhclient -v eth0`, I get this output. The same output (save for the numbers after interval) has always happened, whether the cable is plugged in or not. After running this, `ethtool -S eth0` still shows all zeroes.

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/dc:a6:32:15:f2:94
Sending on   LPF/eth0/dc:a6:32:15:f2:94
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

Comment: How can that be true if it still runs when I unplug the cable?

Comment: `Speed: 10Mb/s   Duplex: Half` - looks like a dodgy cable or what you are connecting the other end of the cable to is very old ... oh, wait `Link detected: no` - there is no connection

Comment: Missed the bit about "whether the cable is plugged in or not", so evidently I'm wrong -- would haven't thought the OS would send packets in the IP layer(s) without all of the layers below it in a certain state.  DHCP uses UDP so it could proceed without an actual exchange of packets.  BTW,  the LEDs should come on when the cable is connected between two running systems.  If they don't, it would mean a hardware problem presuming the OS isn't involved -- something you could investigate to confirm, probably [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) would be the best place.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not going to re-open this, but feel free to ask a new question.  The issue is that you 1) Asked a specific question, 2) Got an answer to that question, 3)  Then, rather than acknowledging it and moving on, *you changed your question based on the answer* in order to ask a follow up question.  You're not new to SE, you know this isn't ramble on discussion style, and there is the broader principle of do unto others.  Please do not waste other people's time by purposefully invalidating answers and transforming questions or you may find you run out of people interested in helping you.

Comment: Sorry, while I may not be entirely new I guess I still don't fully understand it. Sorry for being a bother and thanks for setting me straight

Answer (score 1):

> I can run sudo ip link set eth0 up as much as I want, and it still shows as down.

The output you posted contradicts this.

```
eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
                    ip link sets this ^^                 not this ^
```

To demonstrate:

```
> ip link                                                                                                              
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000               
    link/ether c8:60:00:8a:50:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                                 
    altname enp0s25 
                                                                                                   
> ip link set eno1 up                                                                                                  
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 
    link/ether c8:60:00:8a:50:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                                 
    altname enp0s25
```

This is on a desktop with a cable connected to a router, ie., it is internet capable on eno1, and the output is nearly identical to yours.

The `state DOWN` will only change to up if there is an established IP connection.

So the interface is there and works to some degree.  This doesn't mean it is completely functional, but it does indicate, in response to your question, that the hardware and the OS **do** recognize the existence of the interface and can perhaps exert some control over it.<sup>1</sup>

Having the interface physically up and a cable connected to another running system does not automagically create an internet connection, although of course you can configure the system to automatically connect when the opportunity presents itself.

1. I think setting the first "UP" flag may be a purely software event, because `LOWER_UP`, which has that as a necessary but not sufficient condition, indicates a layer 1 connection (or more specifically that the relevant driver is indicating such, see `man netdevice`).  Layer 1 is the physical layer and there is nothing beneath that, so sans `LOWER_UP` there's no connection of any kind.  It appears when (eg.) DHCP negotiation is initiated, but will remain regardless of whether that succeeds until the interface is set down with `ip link`.  But just setting it "UP" evidently does not prompt the driver to check for or indicate a physical layer connection.